# google calendar with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Calendar in my php application (I use CodeIgniter for this).
I have a problem with my controller calendar.php.

```
<?php 
session_start();

Class Calendar extends Controller {

function Calendar(){
    echo 'start';
    parent::Controller();
    echo 'okkkkkkkk';
    require_once '/home/me/framework/ZendGdata/library/Zend/Loader.php';
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
}
```

but there is a problem with `parent::Controller()` because 'okkkkkk' is not printed. 
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: So "start" *is* printed? Also, you really should update your CI installation to the latest version and make sure error reporting is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
parent::Controller();
```

to

```
parent::__construct();
```

`parent::Controller()` doesn't work in CI because as of CI 2.1.2, the constructors are declared using PHP's `__construct()` method.

As a sidenote, it seems you are using an older version of CI. CI 2.o onwards, the base controller class is called `CI_Controller` as opposed to just `Controller`. You should look into updating your project by replacing the `system` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full working code in this following link https://github.com/omerkamcili/ci_google_calendar_api.

After down loading the code create your service account, OAuth client Id's in the following link http://console.developers.google.com.

Then replace the `client_id,client_secret,redirect_uri's` in your project file in the following path ->  `/project_folder/application/config/client_secret_846685841138-t0a5b9d2i655e7km54md8j440jcg5rr5.apps.googleusercontent.com.json` file
Finally download and replace the `google-api-php-client` in the following file path `/project_folder/application/third_party/google-api-php-client`